# How to compare arrays with best performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare the same table of two different databases with PHP/MySQL (looking for different values).

I already have the fields/values of each table on arrays:

DATABASE1.CONFIGTABLE

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["path"]=>
    string(20) "some/key"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "Unique value"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["path"]=>
    string(21) "some/url"
    ["value"]=>
    string(21) "http://domain1.com/"
  }
}
```

DATABASE2.CONFIGTABLE

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["key"]=>
    string(20) "some/key"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "Unique value"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["key"]=>
    string(21) "some/url"
    ["value"]=>
    string(21) "http://domain2.com/"
  }
}
```

I would like to compare them and return an array with only the values that are different. For example, if all values are the same ("id" and "key") but the "value" field is different, add it to the final array.

Since "Unique value" is the same for both tables but the domains are not, the desire array would be something like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["key"]=>
    string(21) "some/url""
    ["value"]=>
    string(21) "http://domain2.com/"
  }
}
```

Or even better:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["key"]=>
    string(21) "some/url""
    ["value_1"]=>
    string(21) "http://domain1.com/",
    ["value_2"]=>
    string(21) "http://domain2.com/"
  }
}
```

The idea is to look for the best way to do it performance-wise, since the tables can contain thousands of rows.

I hope it is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both databases hosted on the same server? It should possible to write a simple sql query that returns the expected output.

Comment: Also, do both tables always have the same amount of record? Do you just want to check for unmatched `values`, or other columns could have different values too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple SQL query to identify unmatched records between both tables. Assuming that both tables have the same `id`s and `path`s, as shown in your sample data, you can find discrepencies in the `value` column with this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.path,
    t1.value value1,
    t2.value value2
FROM database1.configtable t1
INNR JOIN database2.configtable t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.id 
    AND t1.path = t2.path 
    AND t1.value != t2.value
```